# How to execute a function after given time ?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know how can execute a written function automatically after a given time for specified seconds.

for example i want to run function 10 seconds after executing program for 5 seconds.

Comment: Read carefully guys, this is not a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.7 you can use the sleep method. See here:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: it blocks thread, you should do it without sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at apscheduler. Ir allows you to run scheduled repetitive tasks

http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/

Answer (score 0):

You can sleep for 5 seconds, then execute a determined functionB. But you can't assure to run the functionB for a determined number of seconds unless you sleep it too. For example:

```
import time

def funcA():
    secs = 5
    time.sleep(secs)  # Sleep 5 seconds
    funcB()

def funcB():
    secs = 10
    time.sleep(secs)  # Sleep 10 seconds
```

You can also make this in a thread.

Comment: it blocks thread, you should do it without sleep!